# Alt key gets ignored by Keyman Developer

Tags: unicode, keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

I'm attempting to make a keyboard in [Keyman Developer 9.0](https://help.keyman.com/developer/9.0/). But rules involving any of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys seem to get ignored and produce no output in the debugger.

Here's my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): this keyboard layout code is an attempt to modify the behavior of a single key, the <kbd>Z</kbd> key.

```
store(&VERSION) '9.0'
store(&NAME) 'Sandbox'
begin Unicode > use(main)

group(main) using keys
+ [SHIFT K_Z] > 'Shift! '
+ [LALT K_Z] > 'Lalt! '
+ [RALT K_Z] > 'Ralt! '
```

This compiles cleanly. Then typing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> in the debugger print `Shift!` as intended.

But <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> don't do anything. It's as if those rules get ignored.

Same problem if I don't distinguish between left and right <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys and just use

```
+ [ALT K_Z] > 'Alt! '
```

How do I fix this?

My physical keyboard has a European layout, more specifically for Denmark... though I don't think this should have any effect on this issue.

Comment: You might try running it in the debugger to see what is going on. Using the current beta version of Keyman Developer (10.0.1057.0) I tried it on my American keyboard (in the debugger) and got this output when typing each of the three key combinations in succession: Shift! Lalt! Ralt!

Comment: Yes, there was a limitation in the Keyman Developer 9 debugger that prevented it working with Alt keys. If you install the keyboard with version 9, it should work. However @TomBogle's suggestion of going with 10.0 is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limitation in the Keyman Developer 9.0 debugger that prevents it working with Alt keys.

This limitation has been lifted in version 10.0.

Note that this is only a issue with the *debugger*. If you actually install the keyboard with version 9.0, it should work.

*<sub>Content migrated from [Marc Dudin's comment to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814838/alt-key-gets-ignored-by-keyman-developer/49851657#comment86690225_49814838).</sub>*